# Is it allowed to remove mounted directory from inside Docker container?

Tags: docker

I have a container which is based on tomcat image and I have mounted 'webapps' folder to hosted machine directory '/app/webapps'. Now for some updations I want to remove this webapps folder from inside the container but when I execute command: `rm -rf webapps` below error is produced:

> rm: cannot remove 'webapps': Device or resource busy

So I want to know is it possible to remove mounted directory by executing a Linux command from inside the container or not?

Answer (score 4):

No, you sadly can't remove a volume that is in use by a container which is stated under 'Extended Description' here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_rm/

However, I'd suggest using docker for its strength and restarting the docker container after updating the directory externally.